# How to close a particular window without closing the whole app in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm creating a Tic-Tac-Toe program using `tkinter`, in which I would like to take the name of the user using entry and the next name to be given in a separate window, but before that I would like to automatically close the previous window.

I used a common variable called `root` (`mainloop` also) for displaying all the windows. Once I destroy the `root`, the whole program stops. Should I name a separate variable with `tk.Tk()` to proceed and use it in other windows? I just can't understand.

Can anyone help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, destroying the root will close the entire app.
If you want to close windows while keeping the app running, you can use a `tk.Toplevel` to pop a window open, and be able to close it while continuing other operations.

maybe like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


def popup():
    p = tk.Toplevel(root)
    p.title('popup')
    tk.Label(p, text='I will self destroy in 3 seconds').pack()
    p.after(3000, p.destroy)


root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root, text='pop a new window', command=popup)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```